# Calculation in R across weeks (retention rate) - for loop, or is there a better option?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out a better way of doing a retention rate calculation across weeks.

This is weekly data, so doing it in a for loop is presumably pretty computationally expensive, which would be nice to avoid.

```
r = retention.rate
x = rep(10,52)

y[1] = x[1]
y[2] = x[2]+y[1]*r
y[3] = x[3]+y[2]*r
y[4] = x[4]+y[3]*r
```

And so on.

Currently, I'm doing it in a for loop, like so:

```
for(i in 2:length(y)) {
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i-1] * r
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
y = as.numeric(lapply(1:52, function(i) sum(x[1:i]*r^(0:(i-1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really need to get some practice using vector functions like this.